# Relational algebra, without use of division operator

Tags: relational-algebra

Given :

```
PROFESSOR(NAME,OFFICE,DEPARTMENT,AGE)
COURSE(CNO,TITLE,DEPARTMENT)
ENROLL(CNO,SEMESTER,INSTRUCTOR_NAME,ENROLLMENT)
```

Find names of professors who taught all the courses in their department. Your solution must not use the division operator.

Is this question solvable using relational algebra?

I feel that this is not possible, even with the use of division operator. Unless we do it repeatedly for each professor name or for a particular department.

Any great ideas?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Read [ask] including re homework.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this question solvable using relational algebra?

Yes, it is. "All" is a clue to consider relational division.

But relational division is not a primitive operator. So you can "use" it without using it by using the operators by which it can be defined. There are many sources for learning about "all" and division queries.

(The conditions for tuples to be returned for "all the" and "at least the" queries, including those for which division is and is not appropriate, involve using the formal "forall X" and "not exists X". And "and not" leads to algebraic "minus" while "exists X" leads to algebraic "project *all attributes but X*". And often is is simpler to reason about such conditions using relational subset-of: A first relation is a subset of a second when the tuple membership condition for the first implies the tuple membership condition for the second. And "P implies Q" means "not (P and not Q)". In which "and not" turns up again.)